# Cakephp input prompt text

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following input field in a form:

```
  echo $this->Form->input('website_name');
```

Now i want it to display a prompt text that when the user starts to type disapears

i have tried the following:

```
  echo $this->Form->input('website_name'),array('namespace'=>'Hello world');

  echo $this->Form->input('website_name'),array('title'=>'Hello world');
  echo $this->Form->input('website_name'),array('placeholder' =>'Hello world');
```

but with no luck. Does anyone know how to get a prompt text on these text fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `placeholder` instead of name and title.

```
echo $this->Form->input('website_name',array('placeholder'=>'Hello world'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration is wrong.

```
echo $this->Form->input('website_name'),array('namespace'=>'Hello world');
--------------------------------------^^--
echo $this->Form->input('website_name'),array('title'=>'Hello world');
--------------------------------------^^--
```

must be

```
$this->Form->input('website_name'
array('namespace'=>'Hello world',
'title'=>'Hello world',
 'placeholder' =>'Hello world'));
```

Comment: worked. although its array('placeholder'=>'Hello world', instead of namespace

Comment: sorry i forget to add placeholder in array...now see

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you want:

```
echo $this->Form->input('website_name', array('placeholder' => 'Hello world'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`input()` is a cakePHP method and you are trying to put 2 attributes but wrong. Here is correct form:

```
echo $this->Form->input('website_name', array('placeholder'=>'Hello world'));
```

1. string - `'website_name'`
2. Array  - `array('placeholder'=>'Hello world')`